# Vue3 TS get value of input with ref

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Seems to be so simple problem, however, I don't see any consistent documentation of Vue 3 typescript on how to access an input field and get its value from a function.

```
<template>
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="test"
    ref="input"
  />

  <span @click="testFunc()">Test</span>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
...
setup() {
  const input = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const testFunc = () => {
    if (input.value) {
       console.log(input.value.value); // always undefined
    }
  };

  return {
   input,
   testFunc,
  }
});
```

PS. very new with Vue and typescript. go easy on me :)

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what Field is. There would be `input.value.value` if a ref were input dom element, but in this case it's component instance. In case of inputs it makes more sense to stick to v-model convention, as the answer shows.

Comment: @EstusFlask omg it was it all along. I was using Field from `vee-validate`, it's strange how I can't get value when using that.

Comment: weird thing now is, I can't get the value in form submit if I use normal <input> instead of <Field>

Comment: You can debug input.value. I expect input.value.value to be there for <input> . Any way, that's for learning purpose, you won't need that in properly written component

Comment: "go easy on me :)" .. the fact you need to state this shows how fucked up stack overflow is :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you just can use [the v-model binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#basic-usage).

```
<template>
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="test"
    v-model="input"
  />
</template>
```

If you need to run a function on change, you could use [watch()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watchers). Remember to import watch from 'vue'.

```
watch(input, (newValue, oldValue)=>{
   console.log(newValue, oldValue)
})
```

Hope this helps.

PS: a bit off topic (but since you are fairly new to vue): you also can use `<script setup>`, which simplifies the setup function. [See docs.](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#script-setup)

Comment: sorry i've updated my question. the function is triggered from different button. not from @change.

Comment: Ah, okay, well that should work instantly with v-model. :-)

Comment: But I think you should do `console.log(input.value)`, not `console.log(input.value.value)`.